# script to enable ICS service

Tags: powershell, python, cmd.exe, c#

I try to build script to select private network and enable part of ICS services. I select the private network with these code:

```
{
# Constants
$public = 0
$private = 1

Write-Host "Creating netshare object..."
$netshare = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.HNetShare

Write-Host "Getting public adapter..."
$publicadapter = $netshare.EnumEveryConnection | Where-Object {
    $netshare.NetConnectionProps($_).Name -eq "Local Area Connection"
}#foreach

Write-Host "Getting private adapter..."
$privateadapter = $netshare.EnumEveryConnection | Where-Object {
    $netshare.NetConnectionProps($_).Name -eq "Peer2Peer"
}#foreach

Write-Host "Disabling sharing for adapters...."
$netshare.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection($privateadapter).DisableSharing()
$netshare.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection($publicadapter).DisableSharing()

Start-Sleep -s 3

Write-Host "Enabling sharing for private adapter...."
$netshare.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection($privateadapter).EnableSharing($private)

Write-Host "Enabling sharing for public adapter...."
$netshare.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection($publicadapter).EnableSharing($public)

# Clean up
Remove-Variable netshare
}
```

I want to get all ICS services and enable part of them
someone have any clue?

[image]

Comment: What (ancient) windows / powershell version are you using? -> `$PSVersionTable`

Comment: its windows server 2008